# Convexity and closedness of a set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a question about function sets.

The first set is defined as

$U(t) := [\alpha(t),\beta(t)]$ with $\alpha,\beta : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

I've never seen such a definition of a set. Could anyone explain the meaning here? Is this a set of functions, or an interval of between function values?

Then this set is used in the definition of the second set

$\overline{U} := \lbrace u \in L²(0,1;\mathbb{R}) :  u(t) \in  U(t) \, \mathrm{for \, a.e. \, t \in [0,1]} \rbrace$

And this set is claimed to be both convex and closed.

I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U$ is a set-valued (interval value) function, i.e.,  $U(t)$ is the interval $[\alpha(t),\beta(t)]$.

The set $\overline{U} := \lbrace u \in L²(0,1;\mathbb{R}) :  u(t) \in  U(t) \, \mathrm{for \, a.e. \, t \in [0,1]} \rbrace $ is convex since each  $[\alpha(t),\beta(t)]$ is convex , and it is closed since integral preserves inequalities .